# Download Image which stored in Amazon S3 php script

Tags: php

I have a S3 account to store all images.

```
mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/imagename.JPG
```

This URL is secret , where i am upload restricted user. I have to create Download URL for this secret Image. This Download url only available to uploaded user.

How i can write code in php to download a image file securely.

May be url will look like: `mysite.com/restrictedimage.php?mid=xyztokens234`

Comment: Where is your effort? Or you didn't try to do this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design a simple database table (or configuration file) which records the correlation between tokens and protected URLs, then in your restrictedimage.php script you simply have to check the token and redirect the user to the actual link.

Instead, if you want your keep secret your URLs, you should periodically download and cache the images in your server and output back directly the image, instead of a redirect.

Example code for option 1:

```
$token = isSet($_GET['mid'])?$_GET['mid']:null;
if(!$token) die("No token");
$realURL = retrieveUrlFromToken($token);
if(!$realURL) die("Invalid token");
header("Location: http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/" . $realURL);
```

Example code for option 2:

```
$token = isSet($_GET['mid'])?$_GET['mid']:null;
if(!$token) die("No token");
$realURL = retrieveUrlFromToken($token);
if(!$realURL) die("Invalid token");
$file = file_get_contents("http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/".$realURL);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $file;
```

Notice that `retrieveUrlFromToken` could simply be an identity function, if you don't want to hide the real path, but I'd suggest you to do something better, otherwise the whole script is useless.

Comment: thanks man i got it , this code will not be useless :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to download image File

```
<a href="download.php?filename='imagename.JPG'>Download</a>
```

Download.php

```
<?php

    $filename ="http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/" . $_GET["filename"];
    $buffer = file_get_contents($filename);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    echo $buffer; 
?>
```